# Why some google fonts support only regular style?

Tags: html

For example https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Bebas+Neue
wheras in Canva application you can have thin or regular style

Comment: Guess you need to ask the person that designed the font. Perhaps they could not be bothered?

Answer (score 1):

Some people don't make fonts in so many styles, if you want, you can design your own font.